# How to display specific DOM only in local?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables

.env

> APP_ENV=local

---

```
data() {
        return {
            appEnv: process.env.APP_ENV,
```

only for local set up, I want to display this debugging section.

```
<v-col v-if="appEnv == 'local'" cols="6" sm="6" md="9">{{ urlGroups }} </v-col>
```

I see no error on console, but I also see nothing render from `{{appEnv}}`

What did I miss ?

Comment: If you use Vue CLI, this should be stated. Vue and Vue CLI are not the same.

Comment: Process.env is not available in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a condition in DOM is indirect and unreliable way to debug. Instead `process.env.APP_ENV` needs to be debugged directly, preferably with a breakpoint.

If it's Vue CLI setup that is used to use .env files then the problem is `APP_ENV` is not available for browser and it could be debugged that it's `undefined`.

As [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) states, custom environment variables should have `VUE_APP_` prefix in order to be available in browser. It should be:

```
VUE_APP_ENV=local
```

and accessed like `process.env.APP_ENV` in Vue app.

Comment: Can u please update the answer to include that ?

Comment: Updated. See the remark regarding Vue CLI. .env file is very specific to it. If your setup is different then it will differ for you and likely won't work because there's no 'process' global in browsers, unless it's explicitly defined. Basically Vue CLI uses 'dotenv' Node package to load .env in webpack config and then shims 'process' global in a build with respective process.env value